# BLToolkit custom data provider

Tags: c#, linq, dataprovider, bltoolkit

Is there any examples of custom data provider for BLToolkit?

I need MongoDB provider and InMemory data provider. For example, I am reading some records from xml or files, and need to show them through BLToolkit selections and queries.

Answer (score 0):

You can find the current implementations of the supplied providers [here](https://github.com/igor-tkachev/bltoolkit/tree/master/DataProviders)
and the official MongoDB Driver for C# [here](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-csharp-driver).

Writing a full provider will get fairly complicated as Bltoolkit's api isn't really designed around non-relational data management, but for the basic CRUD operations that your question implies, this will suffice.

HTH